# Use Regex to replace text between multiple occurences of tags

Tags: regex, vba, powerpoint

I want to replace text in the slide notes of a PowerPoint file.

If the text in the slide notes has a single occurrence of the tag my code works.

For multiple occurrences of the tags it does not work.

The input in this case looks like this:

```
This is a first sentence. 
<code1>This second sentence needs to be deleted.</code1>
Here is a third sentence. This one should be kept.
<code1>This fourth sentence needs to be deleted as well.</code1>
```

The output looks like this:

```
This is a first sentence.
```

I want this:

```
This is a first sentence. 
Here is a third sentence. This one should be kept.
```

```vb
Sub sync_text()

    input_text = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).NotesPage.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text

    ' Delete code1
    Set regX_delete = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With regX_delete
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "<code1>(.+)</code1>"
    End With

    output_text = regX_delete.Replace(input_text, " ")

    ActivePresentation.Slides(1).NotesPage.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = output_text

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See here for the answer to this question](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?66149-Use-Regex-in-VBA-to-replace-text-between-tags-in-PowerPoint-(multiple-occurences)&p=395968)  by John Wilson.

Essentially:

"You have set the pattern to be "GREEDY" - this means it will look for the first  and keep looking till it gets to the last  and delete everything in between. Use a ? in the pattern to set to NON GREEDY"

```
.Pattern = "<code1>(.+?)</code1>"
```